# How to configure my Regular Expression dot to match linebreaks?

Tags: regex

i'm trying to figure this out:

```
<STYLE>
lots of text
and
linebreaks
</STYLE>
```

how can i detect ANYTHING that lies inside the style tag (incl. linebreaks)?
i tried .*? but didn't help

thx

Comment: if he is just going to parse between STYLE and /STYLE, using regex is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

`.*` doesn't work with your example text because `.` does not match new lines.  You can either enable single-line mode in your regex implementation (some don't support it, like javascript) or you can use `[\S\s]*` in place of `.*`.

Answer (score 2):

you probably need to add "s" modifier to the regexp. Without "s" dot doesn't match newlines.

remember however, that regexp is a wrong tool for parsing html, better consider a dedicated parsing library available in your language.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a bad way to parse HTML. Jeff Atwood has [a nice article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) on it.